# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex' django throws this error

Tags: python, django

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView
from blog.models import Post

urlpatterns = ['',
                url(r'^$', include('blog.urls'),
                 ListView.as_view(
                 queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by('date')[:10],
                 template_name='blog.html')), ]
```

no idea about this error can someone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `urlpatterns` with a list - which is the only way to do it in 1.10+ - you must not provide an initial pattern prefix argument, which is what you are doing with the empty string there. Remove that completely.

Comment: urlpatterns = ['',
               url(r'^',
                   ListView.as_view(
                       queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by('date')[:10],
                       template_name='blog.html')), ]      i have changed to this still its not working

Comment: Er, you didn't change the relevant thing. *Remove* that first empty string.

Comment: urlpatterns = [url(r'^',
                   ListView.as_view(
                       queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by('date')[:10],
                       template_name='blog.html')), ] solved with ur soln thanks roseman